# How to put an infinite timeout at a specific moment of an Expect script?

Tags: bash, expect

I programed an Except script which makes successive ssh connections : it first connects to a computer, then to another one and finally it does a picocom connection to an embedded system.

I basically wrote the script like that :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 3

spawn ./code_to_connect_to_the_1st_computer.sh

expect "SPECIFIC LOG FROM THE 1st COMPUTER"

send -- "ssh SECOND_COMPUTER"

expect "enter password"

send -- "PASSWORD"

send -- "picocom EMBEDDED_SYSTEM"

expect "enter password"

send -- "PASSWORD"
```

My problem is that once I'm in the embedded system, I get disconnected by the script after the timeout because it stops executing while I need to stay connected.

Anyone knows a way to put some kind of infinite loop at the end of the script to keep the connection ?

Thanks !

Comment: From the `expect` manpage: *An infinite timeout may be designated by the value -1.*

Comment: So, you need to `set` the timeout variable with the magic value.

Comment: add `expect -timeout -1 eof` at the end.

Comment: My problem is that I need to define a short timeout because if don't the expect script won't execute "send -- "picocom EMBEDDED_SYSTEM"" and I don't know why. I put a short timeout of 3s for this reason : after "send -- "PASSWORD"" the script waits something (but I don't know what) but only for 3s and then it proceeds with "send -- "picocom EMBEDDED_SYSTEM"". If I write "set timeout -1", the script is stuck before "send -- "picocom EMBEDDED_SYSTEM"".